# Prohibit the acces to index.php on wamp

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

Wamp is installed on a local server.

How can i prohibit the users from  opening

```
 http://<server-ip>:<port-no>/index.php
```

but i should be able to log into the server and open the index.php

basically, i am trying to restrict the users to see the list of deployed apps on the wamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either a `.htaccess` file or modify your apache configuration to deny users access, only allowing your own IP address (probably 127.0.0.1).

See this page for a good starting guide: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/deny-visitors-by-ip-address/

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.html
              <FilesMatch "^index.php$">
                  Order Deny,Allow 
                  Deny from All 
                  allow from 127.0.0.1
              </FilesMatch>